# How do I track a computed field fetched by a custom JPA @Query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I created a field annotated with the @ReadOnlyProperty so I can track a computed field value. However, when I make a normal findAll query, I receive a SQL Error warning that this column (hasChildren) does not exist. I already tried removing the GET method, but it does not solve the problem at all. I also tried using the @Transient annotation but I could not save the value on my property.

```
@Entity
@Table
public class Parent extends BaseEntity {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @OneToMany( fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Child> childs;

    // Computed column that come from @Query annotation
    @ReadOnlyProperty
    private boolean hasChildren;

    //Getters
    //Setters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try annotating the field with JPAs @Transient. This should tell it not to persist it in the database.

Comment: When I  annotate the field with JPAs @Transient, the property is not changed by the query result.

Comment: have you tried something like hasChildren(){return childs!=null && childs.size>0}

Comment: I simplified the class. In fact, I have 3 classes that could be child os this "parent" class. Because of that, I am using an improved query to search if there is at least one children.